Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame
My code in decrpypting the data that needs to be decrypted. After that it's not going in For loop but directly goes to Catch statement and throws error. Wondering if this something with my permissions or just the code is not correct.
Sample code :
<script runat="server"> 
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1"); 

  try { 
    var mid = '[mid]'; 

    var endpoint = 'https://' + mid + '.recs.igodigital.com/' + mid + '/trigger?item_count=1&include=ProductType|Color&sort_by=sale_price&sort_direction=desc'; 

    var subscriberKey = 'xxx';  // Hardcoded for testing
    var data = " XXXX ";  // Hardcoded data
    var payload = { "trigger_payload": data }; 

    var httpResult = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "application/json", Stringify(payload), []);
    Write("StatusCode: " + httpResult.StatusCode + ", Result: " + httpResult.Response);

    if (httpResult.StatusCode == 200) {
        // Instead of parsing the full JSON, try accessing specific parts of it
        var responseStr = httpResult.Response;
        Write("Response (raw): " + responseStr + "<br>");

        // Try to access a specific part of the response
        var responseJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(responseStr);

        if(responseJSON && responseJSON.someField) {
            Write("Parsed specific field: " + responseJSON.someField + "<br>");
        } else {
            Write("Parsed JSON successfully, but specific field not found.<br>");
        }
    } else {
        Write("HTTP request failed with status code: " + httpResult.StatusCode);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Write("Error: " + Stringify(error) + "<br>");
    if (error.InnerException) {
        Write("Inner Exception: " + Stringify(error.InnerException) + "<br>");
    }
  }
</script>

After successfully printing the decrypted data, it throws this error :

Error: {"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

The complete result is :


StatusCode: 200, Result: {" DATA "} Response (raw): {" DATA "}
Error: {"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}



{ data }  isn't valid JSON.

This means here the result contains the actual data that’s expected. But, in addition to that data there was this error.

The error is due to parsing JSON. Please edit your question and provide a Complete and Reproducible example

Question is complete and all steps are there. I just hide the actual data retrieved from the encrypted string.
